# How to run script flush all Azure Redis

Tags: azure, powershell, redis, azure-cli, azure-redis-cache

I tried to set up the end task after deploying the Web App to clean the cache in Azure Redis to avoid making old caches effective. I tried both command az cli, and Powershell both of them did the same restart, but all data in the Redis cache still did not flush, even in activilogs showing data will be lost after restart. I have tested on both Tier C0 and P1 Redis. Has anyone given me a script to flush all Azure Redis? I am setting only SSL port 3380.

This is the command I run:

-CLI

az redis force-reboot --name $Redis --resource-group $ResourceGroup --reboot-type AllNodes

-Powershell:

Reset-AzRedisCache -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $Redis -RebootType "AllNodes" -Force

-activities Log:
[image]

Check in redis tool manager still have data:
[image]

Thank you for helping me!

setup task Flushall Azure Redis

Answer (score 0):

- Install Redis on [WindowsRedis](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-windows/).

The  command  `force-reboot`  used for Reboot specified Redis node from this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/redis?view=azure-cli-latest#az-redis-force-reboot())

```
az redis force-reboot --reboot-type {AllNodes, PrimaryNode, SecondaryNode}
                      [--ids]
                      [--name]
                      [--resource-group]
                      [--shard-id]
                      [--subscription]
```

- Login to Azure  using `az login`.
- To create a Azure Redis [Cache](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-manage-redis-cache-powershell.md)

```
    New-AzRedisCache -ResourceGroupName myGroup -Name mycache -Location "North Central US"
```

- For Clearing/flush  Azure Redis Cache using PowerShell.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { redis-cli -h <hostname>.redis.cache.windows.net -p <redisPort> -a <password> }

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { redis-cli flushall }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

- Easy way is to go to overview, click on console and execute a `flushall` command:

[image]

**Another method:**

```
$redisServer.FlushAllDatabases() # Dispose connection 

$redis_cache.Dispose() Write-Host "Cache flush done" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```